# Python: "MemoryErrorUnhandled exception in thread started by"

Tags: python, list, memory

I find my code unable to run because of a "MemoryErrorUnhandled exception in thread started by " error.

This is my code:

`def waterMark(surface,hidden,structure=(2,1,5)):
    if sum(structure) == 8 and len(structure) == 3:
        B = int(structure[0])
        G = int(structure[1])
        R = int(structure[2])
        for i in xrange(surface.shape[1]):
            for j in xrange(surface.shape[0]):
                if i < hidden.shape[0] and j < hidden.shape[1]:
                    surface[i,j][0] = surface[i,j][0][:8-B] + hidden[i,j][:B]
                    surface[i,j][1] = surface[i,j][2][:8-G] + hidden[i,j][:G]
                    surface[i,j][2] = surface[i,j][2][:8-R] + hidden[i,j][:R]
    else:
        print 'the param must be 3-dim list or turtle ,and its sum is 8'
    return surface

def to_Bin(array):
    b_list = []

    if len(array.shape) == 2:
        for i in range(array.shape[0]):
            InterVariable = []
            for j in range(array.shape[1]):
                binnum = bin(array[i,j])[2:]
                InterVariable.append((8-len(binnum))*'0'+ binnum)
            b_list.append(InterVariable)

    elif len(array.shape) == 3:
        for i in xrange(array.shape[0]):
            InterVariable = []
            for j in xrange(array.shape[1]):
                InterVariable.append(
                    [(8-len(bin(array[i,j][c])[2:]))*'0'+ \
                     bin(array[i,j][c])[2:] for c in range(3)]
                    )
            b_list.append(InterVariable)

    return np.array(b_list) 


def MED(orgpath,datapath):
    base_img = cv2.imread(orgpath)
    hidden_img = cv2.imread(datapath)
    gray_hidden = cv2.cvtColor(hidden_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    while base_img.size < 2*hidden_img.size:
        base_img = cv2.pyrUp(base_img)
        print 'base_img%d' %(base_img.size)

    gray_b_hidden = to_Bin(gray_hidden)
    bgr_b_base = to_Bin(base_img)
    wm = waterMark(bgr_b_base,gray_b_hidden,(3,2,3))
    encry_img = to_Dec(wm)
    return encry_img

file1 = 'im.jpg'
file2 = 'IMG_0284.jpg'
img = MED(file1,file2)`

The size of file2 is only 1.2M and file1 is 20K, I don't know why the memory is not enough. I want to know how to fit it in memory. Thank you.

The feedback:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "H:\signature.py", line 146, in 
          img = MED(file1,file2)
      File "H:\signature.py", line 139, in MED
          bgr_b_base = to_Bin(base_img)
    MemoryError

Comment: Can you give the whole traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\py_app\dataforstudy\图片签名\signature.py", line 146, in <module>
    img = MED(file1,file2)
  File "H:\py_app\dataforstudy\图片签名\signature.py", line 139, in MED
    bgr_b_base = to_Bin(base_img)
MemoryError

Thank you

Comment: In the method `to_Bin`: are you iterating over the pixels of the image? I assume that the size of the variable `b_list` grows over your available memory. Although the image itself might only have 1.2M, what you store in this list can easily grow bigger. What are you exactly doing in `to_Bin`? What do you store in `b_list`?

Comment: How many pixels does the 1.2M image have?

Comment: >>>base_img = cv2.imread('IMG_0284.jpg')
>>>base_img.size
23970816

Comment: How long are the strings/lists that you append per pixel? How much memory do you have?

Comment: My memory have 4G, and when I run this code my memory use up. I want to know how to reduce consume memory. How can I rewrite the fuction I want to change the pixel image to binary?Thank you.